# Strip down a number and return it every time minus the last digit

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say i have a number 1234567890 andi want to do some sort of loop that creates something usable in an MySQL query.

For example:

Number is `1234567890`.

The usable part in the query should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (1234567890, 123456789, 12345678, 1234567, 123456, 12345, 1234, 123, 12, 1)
```

breaking my head on this one so i hope someone can help me out.

Thank you very much in advance...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

```
where '1234567890' like concat(column, '%') and length(column) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$number = "1234567890"; // Has to be string
$array = array();
while( strlen($number) > 1 )
{
    $array[] = $number;
    $number = substr($number, 0, strlen($number)-1);
}
$strForMySQL = implode(",", $array); // would return "1234567890,123456789,12345678,........1"

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (".$strForMySQL.")";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `substr` to keep stripping the last character of the number with a loop. If you start with an integer, you will need to type cast this into a string for it to work.

```
$x=1234567;
$x=(string)$x;

for($i=0; $i<strlen($x); $i++){
    //Write SQL here or store them in an array, print...etc.
    echo substr($x, 0,strlen($x)-$i);

}
```